# How to detect Application Paused(Not killed) and Resumed(Not created) from a library

Tags: java, android, jar, shared-libraries, aar

I am making a library(say com.library). This library will go in a number of applications. Now This library contains a timer. This timer should stop when the application goes to background and start again when the application goes to foreground.

Now problem is there is no onPause and onResume in Application class. I can not use OnResume and OnPause of Activity as it will start/Stop my timer for every activity switch within the app.

Also top package can be any application that imports the library. Is there any way i can detect same in library with minimal efforts from the applications that will import my library.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this should help you out [image: alt]
futher infromation can be obtained at 
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ComponentCallbacks2.html

Comment: Android provides callback on various states of the app ,the doc given has already the parameters defined for states you might wanna use

Comment: TrimMemory callback are not received when application comes to foreground. I am getting callback of TRIM_MEMORY_UI_HIDDEN  when app goes to background but no callback comes when app comes to foreground...

Comment: for that u can use the application class files onResume method....to get that callback

Comment: For foreground callback,u should use a interface to get callback from the apps application files onResume method

Answer (score 0):

there is an override method which is called `onResume()` you can use it like this:

```
@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();  // Always call the superclass method first

    // Get the Camera instance as the activity achieves full user focus
    if (mCamera == null) {
        initializeCamera(); // Local method to handle camera init
    }
}
```

You can also read this in the [Android Develope Doc](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/pausing.html)

This method is called if the application is resumed! So you can write everything you want to this method.

Comment: OnResume is an Activity Method. When I switch from an activity to another activity, than also onPause and onResume of Activity is called. So My Timer will stop and start for every activity change. I dont want this.